# keep dialog box(?) open after clicking submit button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, razor

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
<li class="active"><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#features">FEATURES</a></li>
<li><a href="#check">CHECK E-MAIL</a></li>
<li><a href="#testimonials">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
<li><a href="#Signup" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>

    <div id="Signup" class="modal hide fade LoginSignup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel2">Sign Up</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>@alert</p>
    <form method="POST" action="" name="signupform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname">
    <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="password1">
        <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign Up" />
        <label>By registering you are automatically agreeing to our <a href="#">Terms of Service</a></label>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

this is from a html5 template that i downloaded somewhere, when i click sign up in the menu (the first code i posted) it opens some kind of dialog box(?) i fill the textboxes just fine and when i click submit it registers just fine and i wanted to keep that dialog box(?) open so i can show a message through the variable alert that says you registered successfully blabla.

i can get everything working including the alert but i cant keep the signup dialog open after submitting so i have to click signup on the menu again to see the alert message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like bootstrap to me. First things first, you have to change the submit button in the pop-up to something like:

```
<span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitform()">Submit</span>
```

Then you have to create the javascript function called "submitform" to submit the signup form data to a webservice or whatever backend you have, read back the response and display the response in the popup itself.